# jQuery returning unexpected font-size value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, font-size

I set the font-size of an element through a CSS file to be 12 pixels. When I inspect the element in Chrome or FF, the value of the font-size attribute is as should be - 12px. But, when I want to get the font-size of that element with jQuery and show it in the console, I get the value 16px. Any ideas on why this is happening?

Thanks!

jQuery code

```
$('p').css("fontSize");
```

Comment: please create a js-fiddle

Comment: the font-size is override by other css rule

Comment: so, you could get computedStyle instead!

Comment: Note that `$('p').css(...` ***only gets the CSS from the first*** paragraph, not any other paragraph in the DOM if you have more than one.

Comment: Check that your browser isn't zoomed in as well.. Been there suffered that.

Comment: @C-link you were right. It was a CSS override. My fault! Thanks you all!